# Django templates - sudden appearance of "&#xFEFF;" in my html

Tags: django, django-templates

Has anyone discovered the sudden appearance of "&#xFEFF;" in their html?

[image]

Comment: it looks like [unicode BOM mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in some template

Answer (score 0):

Fix, copy contents of template into a new html file and delete that html file. Don't ask me how and why this happened.

If anyone comes across this phenomenon, please share your experience.

Answer (score 0):

I my case this package https://pypi.org/project/django-htmlmin/ caused the problem.
I had to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

***I had the same problem.***
***Later, i solved it with the code below***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let html = document.querySelector("html");
 let cleanHTML =html.innerHTML.replace(/[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF]/gim, '');
  html.innerHTML = cleanHTML;

})
```