# Django - "&#xFEFF;" appearing under <body> tag and adding space to page

Tags: html, django, django-templates, visual-studio-2022

I noticed this when i was getting spacing above the navbar, after Inspecting the page i found a random "﻿" under  tag which is causing to add a space on the page.
This doesnt show up if i stick all the html in one file (home.html) and runserver. However, when i start using extends or includes with my base.html, "﻿" pops up.

Any ideas on possible fixes?

I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 - Version 17.5.2

[Inspect Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoC2u.png)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
```

1. Byte Order Mark - it might have something to do with utf-8 with BOM? I've tried copy/pasting in notepad and saving as.. utf-8 without BOM and then pasting back into the html file but it didn't work
2. I used:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            let html = document.querySelector("html");
            let cleanHTML = html.innerHTML.replace(/[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF]/gim, '');
            html.innerHTML = cleanHTML;
        })
```

seems to be removing the problem but i would like to find the root cause of why this is happening instead of pasting code in every project

Comment: I'm guessing you saw this post already based off of your workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114588/django-templates-sudden-appearance-of-xfeff-in-my-html

Answer (score 0):

Just popping by to post the solution i found.

Visual Studio was saving all my html in UNICODE (UTF-8 With Signature)
All i needed to do was change the encoding to UNICODE (UTF-8 Without siganture)

Here are some screenshots on how i did it:

**1. PROBLEM: This was the setting on Advanced save options on all my html:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/888v5.png

**2. FIX: Click on File > Save *html_file* As... > Save with encoding...**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKCVo.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9qCK.png

**3. FIX: and change it to UNICODE (UTF-8 Without signature)**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/saVSa.png

Problem solved!